# Cordova command line on windows after Visual Studio tools installed

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I installed Visual Studio 2015 with support for building apps with Apache Cordova. I would like to be able to build existing Cordova apps outside of Visual Studio, but I can't find the Cordova command line interface. Should I install Cordova again using npm? Will that break the builds for projects created with Visual Studio? VS installed node.js so npm prompt works. I'm new to Cordova BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to be able to build existing Cordova apps outside of Visual Studio, but I can't find the Cordova command line interface. Should I install Cordova again using npm? Will that break the builds for projects created with Visual Studio?

The answer is yes, you can install Cordova again using npm and that won't break the builds for projects created by Visual Studio.

And one more thing to notice, you need to install cordova command line tool globally: `npm install -g cordova`.

Comment: Also: to make sure you get the same build experience in Visual Studio, go into the config designer and check the box that tells VS to use the global version of Cordova. This way the VS tools will use the same globally installed version of Cordova that your CLI uses.